# How to use strong paranmeters in Mailman receiver on Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm doing a test for receiving emails with Mailman gem in Rails4.2.1 (Ruby 2.1.6).
Receiving email is good, but I can't insert the data to a table with strong parameters.
There, the exception error seems to occur by  the error

```
"...ERROR -- : private method `require' called for
 #<ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess:..."
```

I'd like to insert data with strong parameters after receiving email by using mailman gem.
Mailman gem provides Matcher referred to a params, so it may affect such problem.
Do I have something wrong ? 
How can I use the strong parameters in mailman receiver ?

Thank you in advance.
My codes are as follows: mailman_server.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'mailman'

Mailman.config.poll_interval = 10

Mailman.config.pop3 = {
  server: 'pop.sample.com',
  username: 'test@sample.com',
  password: 'password',
  port: 110,                    
  ssl: false
}

Mailman::Application.run do

  to "%event%@sample.com" do
    begin
      UserMailer.receive(message)

      params[:message] = {}
      params[:message][:title] = message.subject
      params[:message][:description] = message.text_part.body.decoded
      @message = Message.new(params.require(:message).permit(:title, :description))

      if @message.save
        puts 'Message was successfully created.'
      end

    rescue Exception => e
      Mailman.logger.error "Exception occurred while receiving message:n#{message}"
      Mailman.logger.error [e, *e.backtrace].join("n")
    end
  end
end
```

And user_mailer.rb:

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def receive(message)
  end
end
```

I tried another method, but got the following similar error.

```
E, [2015-09-15T15:29:26.944316 #2316] ERROR -- : Error encountered processing message: #<Net::POPMail 1>
 NoMethodError: private method `require' called for #<ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess:0x4523cb8>
 C:/Users/gworth-sny/Z_userfolder/rails/mailman_model/app/controllers/messages_rec.rb:10:in `receive'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mailman-0.7.3/lib/mailman/router.rb:58:in `route'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mailman-0.7.3/lib/mailman/message_processor.rb:23:in `block in process'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mailman-0.7.3/lib/mailman/middleware.rb:33:in `call'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mailman-0.7.3/lib/mailman/middleware.rb:33:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mailman-0.7.3/lib/mailman/middleware.rb:38:in `call'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mailman-0.7.3/lib/mailman/middleware.rb:38:in `run'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mailman-0.7.3/lib/mailman/message_processor.rb:22:in `process'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mailman-0.7.3/lib/mailman/receiver/pop3.rb:49:in `block in get_messages'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/pop.rb:665:in `each'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/pop.rb:665:in `each_mail'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mailman-0.7.3/lib/mailman/receiver/pop3.rb:47:in `get_messages'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mailman-0.7.3/lib/mailman/application.rb:140:in `block in polling_loop'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mailman-0.7.3/lib/mailman/application.rb:137:in `loop'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mailman-0.7.3/lib/mailman/application.rb:137:in `polling_loop'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mailman-0.7.3/lib/mailman/application.rb:87:in `run'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mailman-0.7.3/lib/mailman/application.rb:15:in `run'
script/mailman_server.rb:19:in `<main>'
```

The codes that I changed are as follows.

```
Mailman::Application.run do
  to "%event%@sample.com", "MessagesRec#receive" do
    begin

    rescue Exception => e
      Mailman.logger.error "Exception occurred while receiving message:n#{message}"
      Mailman.logger.error [e, *e.backtrace].join("n")
    end
  end
end
```

messages_rec.rb

```
class MessagesRec < ApplicationController    
  def receive(message, params)
    puts "------------ #{message}"
    params[:message] = {}
    params[:message][:title] = message.subject
    params[:message][:description] = message.text_part.body.decoded
    puts "------------ #{params}"
    @message = Message.new(params.require(:message).permit(:title, :description))
    if @message.save
      puts 'Message was successfully created.'
    else
      puts 'Message was lost.'
    end
  end
end
```

Does this error "NoMethodError: private method `require' called " mean that can not use in this mailman process ?
How is it possible ?
Thank you in advance.